# Boost Regex throwing an error

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have the following error when I try to compile my code in g+ compiler using eclipse

```
In function `ZSt19__iterator_categoryIPKSsENSt15iterator_traitsIT_E17iterator_categoryERKS3_':
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_algobase.h:(.text$_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

All I have done is this statement

boost::regex re("\s+"); along with the header #inlucde

Could you kindly tell me how to proceed ?

Comment: If your code is small, please show it and possibly your g++ line if eclipse shows it.  You're not properly linking to a needed library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're not linking to the correct library. Most Boost libraries are header-only, so you don't need to do anything about them at link time. Boost::regex, however, is one of the few that requires that you link with a library along with giving the compiler the proper headers.

After you fix that, you'll want to re-check the escape in your string -- right now your passing "\s", which shouldn't be allowed (at a guess, you probably want "\s+" instead).